# Optimizing MySQL query to reduced runtime

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the query that will going to run on two tables with 60+ million and 400+ million records. Only the table name will be different, otherwise query is same for both the tables.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT A.CUSIP, A.ISIN, A.SEDOL, A.LocalCode, A.MIC, A.ExchgCD, A.PrimaryExchgCD, A.Currency, A.Open, A.High, A.Low, A.Close, A.Mid, A.Ask, A.Last, 
    A.Bid, A.Bidsize, A.Asksize, A.TradedVolume, A.SecID, A.PriceDate, A.MktCloseDate, A.VolFlag, A.IssuerName, A.TotalTrades, A.CloseType, A.SectyCD,
    row_number() OVER (partition by A.CUSIP order by A.MktCloseDate desc) as 'rank'
    from EDI_Price04 A 
    WHERE A.CUSIP IN (
    "91879Q109", "583840509", "583840608", "59001A102", "552848103") AND (A.PrimaryExchgCD = A.ExchgCD) AND A.CloseType='CC'
) t WHERE t.rank <= 3;
```

When `A.CUSIP IN ()` condition have 10-15 values, the query complete in 2-3sec. With 400 values it took 28sec. But I want to make `A.CUSIP IN ()` take 2k-3k value at a time.
This is my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `EDI_Price04` (
  `MIC` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `LocalCode` varchar(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'PricefileSymbol',
  `ISIN` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Currency` varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PriceDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Open` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `High` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Low` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Close` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mid` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ask` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Last` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bid` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `BidSize` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AskSize` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TradedVolume` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SecID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MktCloseDate` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `Volflag` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IssuerName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SectyCD` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SecurityDesc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEDOL` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSIP` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'USCode',
  `PrimaryExchgCD` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExchgCD` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TradedValue` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `TotalTrades` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Comment` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Repush` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CloseType` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`MIC`,`LocalCode`,`Currency`,`SecID`,`MktCloseDate`,`ExchgCD`,`Repush`,`CloseType`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_0` (`MIC`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_1` (`LocalCode`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_2` (`ISIN`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_3` (`PriceDate`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_4` (`SEDOL`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_5` (`CUSIP`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_6` (`PrimaryExchgCD`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_7` (`ExchgCD`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_8` (`CloseType`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_9` (`MktCloseDate`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_CUSIP_ExchgCD_CloseType_MktCloseDate` (`CUSIP`,`ExchgCD`,`CloseType`,`MktCloseDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: When the list for WHERE IN is more wide than 10 values it is recommended to save it to indexed temporary table and use it in a query. Also generated column with the expression `A.PrimaryExchgCD = A.ExchgCD` included into composite index must improve.

Comment: Do you have indexes in the fields you are filtering?

Comment: I wonder if `INDEX(CUSIP, MktCloseDate)` would help.

Comment: Are any of those columns "constant" for a given CUSIP?  That is, could they be moved out of this bulky table into another table?

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT a.* 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.CUSIP ORDER BY A.MktCloseDate DESC) as rank
      FROM EDI_Price04 A 
      WHERE A.CUSIP IN ('91879Q109', '583840509', '583840608', '59001A102', '552848103') AND
            A.PrimaryExchgCD = A.ExchgCD AND
            A.CloseType = 'CC'
     ) t
WHERE t.rank <= 3;
```

The place to start is with an index.  For this query, you want an index on `EDI_Price04(CloseType, CUSIP, ExchgCD, MktCloseDate)`.

Unfortunately, the condition `A.PrimaryExchgCD = A.ExchgCD` prevents index seeks.  If you were to make changes to the query/data, then one approach would be to add a flag when these are the same, rather then looking at the values separately.  That would allow an index on:

```
EDI_Price04(CloseType, IsPrimary, CUSIP, PrimaryExchgCD, ExchgCD, MktCloseDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE(`MIC`,`LocalCode`,`Currency`,`SecID`,`MktCloseDate`,
         `ExchgCD`,`Repush`,`CloseType`),
  -- KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_0` (`MIC`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_1` (`LocalCode`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_2` (`ISIN`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_3` (`PriceDate`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_4` (`SEDOL`),
  -- KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_5` (`CUSIP`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_6` (`PrimaryExchgCD`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_7` (`ExchgCD`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_8` (`CloseType`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_9` (`MktCloseDate`),
  KEY `idx_EDI_Price04_CUSIP_ExchgCD_CloseType_MktCloseDate` (`CUSIP`,
                          `ExchgCD`, `CloseType`, `MktCloseDate`)
  KEY (CUSIP, MktCloseDate)
```

Having so many columns in the PK costs in space and insert time.  So, I added an `id`, which needs to be `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Keys 0 and 5 are redundant because of the rule "If you have `INDEX(a,b)`, `INDEX(a)` redundant.

I added `(CUSIP, MktCloseDate)` in hopes that it will optimize the RANK expression.